# Moving around items in subtab?

Tags: service-cloud-console, console, subtab-apps

How to do I re-order these items? I need different ones to display at the top.

[image]

Comment: Look at the pagelayout associated to the profile and reorder the fields

Answer (score 0):

You can re order your related list by editing it's layout in setup